# How to use get_queryset the right way in Django?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to use `def_queryset` from django to write filters for django-rest-framework views. I have a list view that I want to be able to filter using 4 different fields - either separately or at the same time. That's 15 different combinations (4 single-element, 6 two-element, 4 three-element and 1 four-element). There probably is a smarter way to write those instead of big else statement, as in the following:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = Comment.objects.filter(status=1)
    post = self.request.QUERY_PARAMS.get('post', None)
    parent = self.request.QUERY_PARAMS.get('parent', None)
    author = self.request.QUERY_PARAMS.get('author', None)
    email = self.request.QUERY_PARAMS.get('author', None)

    # this is obviously incomplete

    if post is not None and parent is not None and author is not None and email is not None:
        queryset = queryset.filter(post=post, parent=parent, author=author, email=email)
    elif post is not None and parent is not None and author is not None:
        queryset = queryset.filter(post=post, parent=parent, author=author)
    elif post is not None and parent is not None and email is not None:
        queryset = queryset.filter(post=post, parent=parent, email=email)
    elif parent is not None and author is not None and email is not None:
        queryset = queryset.filter(parent=parent, author=author, email=email)

    return queryset
```

I don't want to use an additional library such as django-filters. Any ideas how to write those simpler and possibly reuse across different views would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can chain `filter` calls (as you already did after the first call):

```
if post is not None:
    queryset = queryset.filter(post=post)
if parent is not None:
    queryset = queryset.filter(parent=parent)
...
```

Note the `if` instead of `elif`.